# What's the purpose of Vox Populi badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

What's the purpose of **Vox Populi** badge?

I've learned that each badge on StackExchange is promoting some kind of behaviour, which the operators of the site find positive. AFAIK to receive Vox Populi badge it is required to vote on 30 questions (reaching vote limit) and than to 10 answers (thus using additional limit for answers), am I right?

I've once had many good questions and answers to upvote, but after reaching the first vote limit I wasn't able to upvote neither questions nor answers, and I haven't got this badge, so I thought it's possible only by such voting pattern.

I don't understand why the pattern of voting first only on questions, then only on answers, should be favoured by community and granted with badge. Maybe I'm not fully understanding the pattern required to get the badge, or I'm not seeing the big picture behind it... So please, give me the missing knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> AFAIK to receive Vox Populi badge it is required to vote on 30 questions (reaching vote limit) and than to 10 answers (thus using additional limit for answers), am I right?

No, you need only vote on ten questions, but you must have done that before you reach the usual 30 votes limit.

The behaviour the badge shall promote is

1. voting on posts,
2. voting on questions in particular.

Comment: The inparticular is important here because there was a time when some of the bigwigs felt that voting on questions was lower than desireable, and designed some rules to promote it. This badge was one of them as was no cost to downvoting questions.